# MS Sync Framework 2.1 Sync Clients but can't connect to clients through connection string

Tags: sql, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a set up where there is one central SQL Server and 100s of clients. I have designed a Windows app, where I can do sync between server/clients locally for testing and also for clients within same network of server.

But in real-time scenario, I am not able to get the connection strings of clients as its opposed to the business rules and data security.

So, I am looking for ways to connect to the client SQL servers.

Comment: Why don't you get the clients to connect to the central server instead of the other way around?

Comment: JuneT -- If I have to get clients to connect to server then I need to install my app at each client place. I would like to handle the sync from one central place for all the clients.

Comment: If you want the central server to connect to clients without knowing the SQL connection, you will have to deploy a WCF service on the client side to do the sync. You still need to deploy something to the client, plus you need to keep track of all client endpoints, punch holes on their firewalls, etc. Getting the client to connect to the server is the better option imho.

Comment: JuneT-Yeah you are right and I changed my app to connect to server from client side.Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to summarize the answer based on the comments above, get you clients to connect to the server instead of the server connecting to the clients.

this way, you central server doenst have to keep track of all the clients, their addresses, client firewalls, etc...

you can implement an n-tier sync setup where you have a WCF sync service on the server side that your clients can connect to during sync.

Comment: Hi JuneT here using WCF, how do I execute Sunchronise() method, as it needs the connection of the remote server?

Comment: Using WCF, what you have on the client is a proxy to the service. Your service contains the actual connection to the database. Your clients point to the WCF service endpoint, not the server database.

Comment: Hi JuneT thanks for the answer.One last thing how do i track Syncprogress event in N-Tier?

Comment: if you're using n-tier, the events from the WCF service side of things are on another computer. i don't think you'd want the WCF service to do a callback to your client for the sync progress event. you can if you want to, but that's impractical.

Comment: So then how will I track the changes applied like downloaded/uploaded for each table?

Comment: catch the event on the server then log it somewhere... as i have mentioned, service side events fire on the server side. not unless you want a callback to your client for those events, you can't listen to those events on the client side. if you need something from the server operations, log it somewhere and get it from there. (e.g., log it to table, then have a separate wcf service call to retrieve that)